# Is there any API to anticipate an exe not being reachable via Path environment variable

Tags: windows, winapi, path, environment-variables

So I need to triage my PATH environment variable and add extra folders so it can find a certain executable.  I was wondering is there a way to mimic how the Windows OS walks all the directories in the path to see if it "reaches" an exe?

I know I could write a program but ideally there is a Windows API call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PathFindOnPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773594%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) takes in a file name and returns the fully qualified file path, if the file is found. Note, however, that it also looks in standard directories, in addition to `PATH`.